# Python Module is already installed but ModuleNotFound

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, jupyter, xlsxwriter

I am still a beginner in Python.

I use Jupyter Notebook and want to import XlsxWriter, but it doesnt seem to work.

This is what I do in the Notebook which i usually open through the pycharm terminal:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install --user XlsxWriter

import XlsxWriter
```

However i get the following error message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: XlsxWriter in c:\users\rober\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (3.0.3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [8], in <cell line: 6>()
      3 import sys
      4 get_ipython().system('{sys.executable} -m pip install --user XlsxWriter')
----> 6 import XlsxWriter

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'XlsxWriter'
```

Does anyone have an idea what is the problem here?
A simple Script using XlsxWriter in PyCharm works perfectly fine.

Comment: @It_is_Chris Thanks for your Answer. I only have one Python version installed 3.10.4. The XlsxWriter install i did in the terminal as well as in the notebook (after it didnt work with the terminal)

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that you have the wrong case on the import . . . it is `import xlsxwriter` not `import XlsxWriter`  Case matters for imports

Comment: @It_is_Chris omg.. how coul i make such a mistake. Thank you alot !!

Answer (score 1):

you need to install xlsxwriter first

```
pip install xlsxwriter
```

ref : https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-no-module-named-xlsxwriter